# Input vectors active scan zap owasp

Tags: security, owasp, zap

I'm a young student doing an internship in a company (and a pure beginner in the security field). And my company asked me to do security tests with zap owasp on their web application. I wanted to know what are the recommended input vectors to run an optimal active scan? I've already tried to run several active scans with as many options as possible but it never finishes because it takes hours on the first step and never finishes because I leave it running at night and when I come back it has stopped. I did a lot of research and I don't have the impression that the sites I found linger on the explanations concerning the input vectors of an active scan. On the forums people seem to talk more about input vectors through APIs. Would it be more optimal in my situation to go through the APIs?

Thank you for your attention,
I hope you can advise me!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My experience with OWASP ZAP was, that compared to Burp the tool was slower and had memory handling problems when the test took to long. You can play with choosing the technologies and server/DB types when starting an active scan, but it will probably not help if the tested application is big. I'd rather cut the pentest into smaller parts like:

1. Choosing one dialog of the application you want to test
2. Clicking manually through everything there is on the dialog
3. Running the active scan and analysing the output
4. Performing manual tests to confirm the found bugs
5. Going back to point 1 unless there is nothing more to be tested
6. Consolidating the test results

You should also look into the generated traffic to verify, if OWASP ZAP is running correctly and if the generated payloads make sense. A common mistake is running OWASP ZAP against an unauthenticated application or loosing the auth tokens somewhere in the middle of the test. The test does not make any sense after this happens.

Comment: Hello Marek, thank you very much for your answer! I have a few questions. Every time I come back to step 1, I have to delete the links I've already visited so that it doesn't scan over them again I guess? How do we know if the generated traffic is suspicious?

Comment: If all your traffic is rejected with 401, 403, 404 than there is something wrong. Start a new scan every time you change the dialog so all existing data is removed from memory (but of course save the result to disc before).

Answer (score 3):

TBH input vectors are not the first place I would start. You first need to understand why ZAP is taking so long. I wrote a blog about this some time ago which is still pretty relevant: https://blog.mozilla.org/security/2013/07/10/how-to-speed-up-owasp-zap-scans/

Is your site really big or does it just contain a lot of data driven content. Theres no point in scanning 100s or 1000s of pages that actually have the same code behind them. We also have a ZAP User Group on which you should get faster and more pertinant advice https://groups.google.com/group/zaproxy-users

Comment: Thank you for your response. I read your article. It was very informative. Indeed, I remember going through several pages of data on the application looking for different types of entries. In the end I found very little variation in it but Zap most likely recorded all these urls (about 70) and repeated the same attack several times. However it wasn't just a slowdown since I let it run all night. It had already been running for 3, 4 hours when I left (around 6, 7 pm). When I came back in the morning, it had stopped and still hadn't finished the first stage.

Comment: However, in the last few days I combined Marek's technique with an idea of a colleague. I created several sessions for several parts of my site and launched several attacks. Except that for each attack, I check one option only in the input vectors. All the attacks ended except one that I stopped because its behavior was too much like my first test (it was going to never end). For this attack the option I checked was "HTTP Headers with all requests".

Comment: Afterwards I also tried to set the number of threats but I still don't know how to determine an optimal number for my machine. I need to do some more research on it.

In the end I have the impression that it's related to several things. But now that I know all that, I'll be able to optimize. I don't know if my attack method is perfect (probably not) but at least I have results to exploit. Thank you for details :)